# Python : How does `while` loop work in python when reading lines?

Tags: python, while-loop

How does `while` loop work in python when reading lines?

```
state=True #can be set to {anyInterger,True,False}
while state:
    #do a task
    #if task done change state to exit loop
```

so depending on the `state` variable while loop is executed, and `type(state)` can be **bool,int**

but to read lines from file using `while` as mentioned below

```
f=open('test.txt','r')
line_data=[]
line=f.readline()
while line:
    line_data.append(line)
    line=f.readline()
f.close()
```

after reading all lines finally `line=''` but `type('')` is **str**

So how did `while` loop terminate?

*I knew this could be done better using `with` and `for` , reason for not using while loop for this purpose would be helpful*

Comment: `bool('') == False`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: reason for not using while loop.......
https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few implicit boolean conversions in Python.
1) `bool(0)` evaluates to False, any other integers evaluate to `True`
2) `bool('')`, `bool([])`, `bool({})` also evaluate to `False`. This is useful to test whether a container has any items in it (non-empty strings, lists, dicts etc. evaluate to `True`)

So in your case `readline` read the empty string, which got implicitly turned to `bool` and evaluated to `False`, therefore the loop has terminated

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you use a variable as a condition to an `if` or a `while` loop it is evaluated as a boolean value. In Python an empty string is treated as `False`, therefore the `while` loop terminates.

> reason for not using while loop for this purpose would be helpful

You should ask for a reason to **use** a `while` loop for this purpose.

Compare this:

```
f = open('test.txt','r')
line_data = []
line = f.readline()
while line:
    line_data.append(line)
    line = f.readline()
f.close()
```

To that:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
     lines = f.readlines()
```

Comment: Why do you remove the first line?

Comment: The first call to `append` in the OP's code will append the first line.

Comment: @DavidCullen Thanks, you are correct. Updated my answer.

Comment: how is this reason to use while loop ... even by comparing number of lines , the code with `while` loop is longer than `with`

Comment: @rainversion_3 This is exactly what I meant. There is absolutely no reason to use a `while` loop here.

Answer (score 1):

`f.readline()` is a generator object that returns `''` at the end of the file. But `''` has a falsy value:

```
>>> f.readline()
''
>>> bool('')
False
```

Hence, when the `while` evaluates the line at EOF (End Of File), the value is the same as `False`.

The following values are considered `False` (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html)):

> ```
> None
> False
> zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
> any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
> any empty mapping, for example, {}.
> instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a __nonzero__() or __len__() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Empty string is treated as **False** in python. So, it won't enter the loop. FYI the better way of looping over the lines is

```
line_data = []
for line in f.readlines():
    line_data.append(line)
```

You can even do like this also.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    line_data = [line for line in f.readlines()
```

Comment: `f.readlines()` already returns a list. It is totally wasteful to create a list comprehension from it.

Comment: Yes, it is. It just for his understanding purpose.

Comment: And `readlines()` is just a waste of memory. `for line in f:` is enough.

Answer (score -1):

You can add:

```
if len(line) < 2:
    break
```

or alternatively:

```
if line == "''":
    break
```